# How can I create a layout like this where both sides are always the same height?

Tags: html, css, layout, internet-explorer-8

How can I create a layout like the following using HTML and CSS?

[image: Layout sample]

I'd prefer not to use a table because the info that will go in each of the three cells is not tabular at all.

Also, the design needs to be flexible in that if the content on one side is vertically longer than the content on the other side, then the shorter side will stretch down so that it's the same height as the other side. Because the content is quite varied though, there's no way of knowing ahead of time which side will be longer, so no assumptions can be made.

Lastly, this design needs to hold up in IE8 and the vertical line in the middle must be perfectly in the middle, although the horizontal line on the left side does not have to be vertically centered.

Thank you.

Comment: This can be achievable using CSS display table. http://quirksmode.org/css/css2/display.html#table
And make divs act like a table.

Comment: Which is essentially the same thing as using a table. Anyway, I think you're right in that this layout is only achievable by using a table in one form or another. Thank you.

Comment: I do not think you can do that if the two rectangles on the left both need to be the same height. Even with a table. The only way will be for you to use JavaScript for such a thing. If they do not need to be the same height, then a table is easy, the column on the right has a `rowspan="2"`, and voilà.

Comment: Note that you said IE8 too... in Mozilla CSS we have a calc() which can be used to calculate dimensions dynamically. But IE8 does have very limited support for that one, if any. http://caniuse.com/calc

Comment: Yeah, I'm just going to go with either a table or use the `display: table` properties. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

here's a quick thingy I have made, you'll need to adjust it to your needs, but it works just like you ask

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
<div class="left">
<div class="left1">
blah
</div>
<div class="left2">
blah blah
</div>
</div>

<div class="right">
 blahhasgdgas djkasghd kasdkjgsad 
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
*{-webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */}
.container{padding:0; margin:0; position:absolute; top:0; left:0; bottom:0; right:0; width:100%; height:100%}
.left{height:100%;box-sizing: border-box;background:#fc0; margin:0; width:50%; float:left; padding:10px}
.left1{height:49%; background:#845; margin:1%; padding:1%}
.left2{height:49%; background:#845; margin:1%; padding:1%}
.right{height:100%;box-sizing: border-box;background:#654; margin:0; width:50%; float:left; padding:10px}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not what I wanted. It's partially my fault though, but I didn't explain that the layout I want isn't a full-page layout, it's just a layout for a part of the header. As such, `height: 100%` (or any height, for that matter) is too inflexible. Furthermore, the percentage widths are no good because the site already has a style guide for what the width of the borders have to be in pixels. Thank you for your answer though.